# Nesting MaterialUI HtmlTooltip inside of Material UI Select MenuItem / Synthetic event(?) problem in select onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, react-hooks

**---GOAL---**

I am attempting to have a Material UI select with MenuItems that are wrapped in HtmlTooltips, which display hover information about each list choice.

I'm keeping it simple intentionally now as a PoC and will map it dynamically later.

**---CURRENT CODE---**

I am using the controller/view pattern and have the following material UI Select component in the view:

```
<FormControl
  variant="outlined"
>
  <InputLabel id="owner">Owner</InputLabel>

  <Select
    labelId="owner"
    id="owner"
    defaultValue="0"
    value={props.owner}
    onChange={props.handleOwnerChange}
  >
    <MenuItem id="none" value="none" disabled>
      (Select a Value)
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem id="231-abc" value="231-abc" disabled>
      Charlie Person
    </MenuItem>

    <HtmlTooltip
      title={
        <>
          <Typography color="inherit">
            Steve Human
          </Typography>
          <b>{"Next PTO:"}</b>{" "}
          <i style={{ color: "red" }}>
            {" 12/25/20-01/01/20"}
          </i>
        </>
      }
    >
      <MenuItem id="123-abc" value="123-abc">
        Steve Human
      </MenuItem>
    </HtmlTooltip>
    
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

...in the controller, my state getter/setter...

```
   const [owner, setOwner] = useState("null");
```

...and also in the controller, a function which the select uses to change the state value when a list item is selected:

```
 const handleOwnerChange = (event) => {
      setOwner(event.target.value); //
 };
```

event.target.value is undefined in this case for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was after working trying Eric's suggestion. Here is what I ended up needing to do:

Basically, I just needed to:

- Reverse the order of the component wrapping - Wrap the HtmlTooltip WITH the MenuItem instead of wrapping the MenuItem with the HtmlTooltip.
- Enclose the list item text in a div

**---WORKING CODE---**

I am using the controller/view pattern and have the following material UI Select component in the view:

```
 <FormControl
   variant="outlined"
 >
  <InputLabel id="owner">Owner</InputLabel>

   <Select
     labelId="owner"
     id="owner"
     defaultValue="none"
     value={props.owner}
     onChange={props.handleOwnerChange}
   >
     <MenuItem id="none" value="none" disabled>
       (Select a Value)
     </MenuItem>

     <MenuItem id="231-abc" value="231-abc" disabled>
       Charlie Person
     </MenuItem>

     <MenuItem id="123-abc" value="123-abc">
       <HtmlTooltip
         title={
           <>
             <Typography color="inherit">
               Steve Human
             </Typography>
             <b>{"Next PTO:"}</b>{" "}
             <i style={{ color: "red" }}>
             {" 12/25/20-01/01/20"}
             </i>
           </>
         }
      >
        <div>Steve Human</div>
      </HtmlTooltip>
   </MenuItem>

   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

...in the controller, my state getter/setter...

```
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState("none");
```

...and also in the controller, a function which the select uses to change the state value when a list item is selected:

```
  const handleOwnerChange = (event) => {
       setOwner(event.currentTarget.id);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is async when you use setOwner(event.target.value), you need to save the event target value to a variable instead of using it directly in setOwner.
For more details, refer to [here](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling).

> Event pooling
>
> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
> object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
> event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
> such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

```
function onClick(event) {
  console.log(event); // => nullified object.
  console.log(event.type); // => "click"
  var eventType = event.type; // => "click"

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(event.type); // => null
    console.log(eventType); // => "click"
  }, 0);

  this.setState({clickEvent: event}); // Won't work. this.state.clickEvent will only contain null values.
  this.setState({eventType: event.type}); // You can still export event properties.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I read a little bit about it, tried out the sample code and tried to adapt it to my needs. The sample code worked when attempting to use it, but when I subbed in event.target.value as the variable instead of the event.type, everything ended up still being null if you have any other thoughts. Adding the attempt to the main thread for reference. Thanks again!